# Is there a way to reconstruct destroyed outpost in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

The empire just lost the newly constructed outpost, and the invested 200 influence with it, to piracy.

If the fleet will destroy the pirates in this system and a construction ship will arrive - is it possible to reconstruct that Outpost?

In other words - are the 200 influence points lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to rebuild it again, you'll need to spend another 200 influence.

The 200 influence was a cost to build the outpost; you spent it. This is the same as the mineral cost for building stations- you don't get that back when it is destroyed/disbanded either.

Comment: A sad day to the young Empire, a good achievement to the rebels. That's what makes this game so good (playing Iron mode :-) )